# How to run tagged rspec tests with parallel_tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, parallel-processing

I want to execute my rspec tests in parallel

If I need all tests to perform on 6 cores I use `bundle exec rake parallel:spec[6]`

How can I specify a tag option for spec rake, e.g. `--tag ~chat`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use SPEC_OPTS environment variable for passing options to rspec in this case.

Example:

```
$ SPEC_OPTS='--tag ~chat' bundle exec rake parallel:spec[6]
```